# Why is tinyxml2 failing to parse a Traffic Server xml file?

Tags: c++, tinyxml2

Using [tinyxml2](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml2/), I'm trying to parse this Traffic Server config file:

```
<LogFormat>
    <Name = "simple"/>
    <Format = "simple"/> 
</LogFormat>

<LogObject>
     <Format = "simple"/>
     <Filename = "simple.log"/>
     <Mode = "ascii"/> 
</LogObject>
```

Traffic server XML config format is described [here](https://docs.trafficserver.apache.org/en/6.2.x/admin-guide/files/logs_xml.config.en.html#examples):

`LoadFile()` gives me this error:

```
"Error=XML_ERROR_PARSING_ELEMENT ErrorID=6 (0x6) Line number=2"
```

What is wrong with the `Name` element? Can tinyxml2 simply not parse Traffic Server XML config files?

Comment: The config format appears to be named and documented misleadingly. It is not XML. It is "modeled after XML".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<Name = "simple"/>` is not a valid XML element. Valid XML element is something like

```
<LogFormat>
    <Name value="simple"/>
    <Format value="simple"/> 
</LogFormat>
```

or

```
<LogFormat name="simple" format="simple"/> 
</LogFormat>
```

Thus Traffic server `logs_xml.config` config file is not in the XML format, and tinyxml cannot parse it.